# How to transform xml data into rows and columns?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**Here is my input XML:**

```
<data>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>3</node>
    <node>4</node>
    <node>5</node>
    <node>6</node>
    <node>7</node>
    <node>8</node>
</data>
```

**Required HTML output table:**

row = 2

```
1 | 3 | 5 | 7
2 | 4 | 6 | 8
```

row = 3

```
1 | 4 | 7
2 | 5 | 8
3 | 6 |
```

**XSLT-1.0: ??**

How do i transform the above xml to the above structure in html. The number of rows is not predefined and will be provided as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="rows" select="2" />

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="node[position() &lt;= $rows]">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position() mod $rows"/>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../node[position() mod $rows = $i]">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the list of nodes

```
<xsl:variable name="nodes" select="/data/node"/>
```

you need to create one row for each of the first *n* nodes

```
<xsl:for-each select="$nodes[position() &lt;= $numRows]">
  <xsl:variable name="rowNum" select="position()"/>
  <tr>
```

Then within the row the cells can be selected by modulo arithmetic - the first row is node 1, n+1, 2n+1 etc, the second row is 2, n+2, ...

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$nodes[position() mod $numRows = $rowNum]">
```

---

Edit: as pointed out in the comments this won't work for the last row - you need to change the definition of `rowNum` to be modulo `numRows` too:

```
  <xsl:variable name="rowNum" select="position() mod $numRows"/>
```

because the modulo value for the last row is 0 rather than n.

Comment: I am afraid that won't work correctly because mod is zero-based, while position() starts from 1.

Comment: @michael.hor257k hmm, yes, I didn't quite think it right through. What I have will work up to row `n-1` but will fail on the last row.